# Two programs sharing the same mysql database - which tables have been created due to each?

Tags: mysql

I have two programs concurrently sharing the same mysql database, each program creating his own set of tables in the database (table names are dynamically chosen as the programs run).

What I need is to be able to identify which tables have been created due to each program, at any point in time. Is this something feasible?

Comment: That is generally a bad idea. Short of storing the information in a table they can agree upon, the only other way would be to make some machine identifier a part of the "dynamically chosen" name... and be very certain they don't collide or have ambiquity.

Comment: not really. you could poke around the general query log (if it's on), but likely the table manipulation stuff has long since fallen off the end of the log, and mysql doesn't keep audit logs for such things anyways. but note that mysql has no awareness of your apps. it only sees users connecting, and if the two apps share the same user account, you really will be hosed.

Comment: Take a look to the reference manual: [MySQL Server Logs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-logs.html)

Comment: normally you could use different Schemata (or "databases" in mysql speek). `create database  prog1; create database prog2;`. you can join over both databases.

Answer (score 0):

This very much depends on what you really want to solve. You can use different "databases" on the same server and connection, I think "schema" is the usual RDBMS name for it. Most operations work about different schemes now, there have been restrictions in the past.

```
create database prog1;
create database prog2;
```

in prog1 you write

```
create table prog1.dynamicsomewhatever (id int, name varchar);
```

in prog2 you write

```
create table prog2.dynamicotherwhatnever (id int, city varchar);
```

then you can join by

```
select p1.id, p1.name, p2.city 
from prog1.dynamicsomewhatever p1
inner join prog2.dynamicotherwhatnever p2 on p1.id = p2.id
```

Does this help? Otherwise clarify what you really want.

Comment: thanks all of you for the feedback. @flaschenpost: unfortunately I cannot use 2 databases at this point, otherwise this would have been easy. The difficulty lies in precisely the fact that they are sharing concurrently the same database.

Comment: @MarkB: I am not sure whether I can use the user account to distinguish between the two apps, but will I give it a try.

Comment: @Alex: can you control the table name generation? Then create the table names with a prefix. Otherwise I see only different users as a hint or logfile analysis and separation of different servers (if the two programs run on different servers).